# Openlayers 6. Set icon in the feature

Tags: javascript, openlayers

How can I put an icon under the text in the feature?
I've already tried this, but it's not working

```
   const style = new Style({
        stroke: new Stroke({
            color: '#969696',
            width: 2
        }),
        text: new Text({
            font: '14px Calibri,sans-serif',
            fill: new Fill({ color: '#000' }),
            stroke: new Stroke({
                color: '#fff',
                width: 2
            })
        }),
        image: new Icon({
            src: 'https://flagcdn.com/w20/aq.png',
            crossOrigin: ''
        })
    });
```

Comment: `image` is not used for polygon geometries. But you can use a style array and specify a geometry (usually the interior point or points) in the style to display an icon https://codesandbox.io/s/style-renderer-forked-jnptnw?file=/main.js

Comment: wow! Thanks, that exactly what I was searching!